# wget not working with domain on local machine

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts, wget

Basically - I have some PHP scripts that need to be run as cron jobs.

Lets say the script needing to be run is: http://admin.somedomain.com/cron_jobs/get_stats

If I run the script from the local machine it gives me a 404 Not Found error.

So I entered the following into /etc/hosts

```
XX.XX.XX.45    admin.somedomain.com
```

Now wget works fine from the local machine to that domain. However when I restart Apache that domain no longer works. Here is the config for that site in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
NameVirtualHost XX.XX.XX.45:80

<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.45:80>
    ServerName admin.somedomain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.somedomain.com/
    <Directory "/var/www/admin.somedomain.com">
            allowoverride all
          Options Indexes
          order deny,allow
           allow from all
       </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/admin.somedomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/admin.somedomain.com-access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It just goes to the default site config showing "It Works".

If I take out that setting in /etc/hosts and restart apache the website at that domain works fine again.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try `wget --header="Host: admin.somedomain.com" http://localhost/cron_jobs/get_stats` (That's one line.)

Comment: ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

try `httpd -S` that should give you list of all configured virtualhosts including yours. Also verify that your directory "/var/www/admin.somedomain.com/" exists and also take a look in logs and see what they're saying...

Comment: command not found for httpd -S. And yes, /var/www/admin.somedomain.com/ is there.

Comment: sudo `which httpd` -S find your httpd and run it w/ -S

Comment: 'which httpd' gives me no output. The system is running debian.

Comment: In Debian it's `apache2` instead of `httpd`.

Comment: Thanks - Running `apache2 -S` from root returns `apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}`

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you need to run the scripts through Apache, triggered by an HTTP client?  What about just running them directly from cron?

```
0 4 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script
```

Comment: I already tried this. They are Code Igniter virtual addresses - so there is no full path to them unfortunately.